# why bootstrap icon bar disappears

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

*please correct me if i make any mistakes to formate the  question here.

It is a `Bootstrap` web page.

The code is here:     http://jsbin.com/tufemon/2/edit?html,css,output

When i shrink my web pages my menu becomes into icon bar. But after while, when i shrink more,the icon bars goes into the page, like below images.
    [image]
    [image]

Shrink,wide the page, the menu will be icon bar.
If there is any problem in formatting the question, please let me know.

Comment: It is a layout issue, but it is impossible to really tell what is going on without seeing the code.

Comment: @bitz can you please go to this link and check? and why some one making me negetive value? i told him to suggest me how to format.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width from .navbar class  or set 100%

```
 .navbar  {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 586px; /* Remove 586px or set 100% */
}
```

Comment: thanks lot.. it worked :) . dont know, why someone mark me as negetive. I am not expert,thats why came here. I really thankful to you.